# How to write many cells to a text file

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code to extract lithology depth information from a borehole data.

Each lithology has two depths: top depth and bottom depth. They look like this:

```
Sandstone '830.212' '828.222'
Siltstone '832.612' '830.922'
```

each type of lithology has different dimensions of cell.

```
sandstone 12*2 cell
coal 1*2 cell
mudstone 14*2 cell etc.
```

How can I write these information to a text file?

It  seems like I could use dmwrite, but I'd have problem forming a datamatrix because each type of rock has two depths.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you clarify that those cell elements are actually *strings* as opposed to *numbers*? My answer assumes they are strings.

Comment: Hi  reve_etrange, each cell elements are numbers. Actually, they are strings, anyway, i can use str2double change them. The thing is that I have many different cell arrays such as sandstone,mudstone,coal, etc. And each cell array has different dimensions such as sandstone cell array has 12*2 cells. So I was thinking to create a DataMatrix and then use dmwrite to write those cells to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

For cell arrays of strings, I use the following simple function, which is placed in `C:\Users\NAME\Documents\MATLAB\@cell` or the equivalent userpath on your platform (`~/Documents/MATLAB/@cell`). The `@cell` name informs MATLAB that the functions within `@cell` are to be used with cell arrays only.

```
function csvwrite(fileName,cellArray)

fid = fopen(fileName,'w');
for i=1:size(cellArray,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%s,',cellArray{i,1:end-1});
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',cellArray{i,end});
end
fclose(fid);
```

If you need traditional Windows/DOS line endings, replace "\n" with "\n\r" in the second `fprintf` call. You might also replace "," in the first call with "\t" if you want tabs.

For numerical arrays you can use the `csvwrite` function included with MATLAB.

If you have to use cell arrays with mixed data types, the function must be modified to accept an array for format specifiers.

```
function csvwrite(fileName,cellArray,spec)

fid = fopen(fileName,'w');
for i=1:size(cellArray,1)
    fprintf([spec '\n'],cellArray{i,1:end});
end
fclose(fid);
```

For an array with rows similar to: `{ 1 3 5 'string1' string2' }` you would use `spec = '%d,%d,%s,%s'`, for example.

Based on these examples you could write a more sophisticated function which tests the type of the data in each cell and constructs a format string to match, in case you will have completely unknown array contents.

Comment: Hi reve_etrange
Thanks for your help! I just saw your answer.I'll take a look at this.This really helps!