# how could i write the content of a cell array or matrix into a text-file?

Tags: matlab

```
I have got a cell array Ystg of size 219*1 and i want to write it into a text file .
```

i tried this code but doesn't work

```
    C = Ystg.';
fid = fopen('file.dlm', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '"%s"\t"%s"\t"%d"\t"%s"\t\n', C{:});
fclose(fid);`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv8zU.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369077/how-to-write-many-cells-to-a-text-file?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708871/write-a-cell-array-in-text-file-using-matlab?rq=1

Comment: First google hit - [MATLAB examples: Export Cell Array to Text File](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex07445498-export-cell-array-to-text-file)

Comment: I google it and i tried several codes but no benefit

Comment: Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Comment: Edit your question to show the code you tried

Comment: i have edit it , plz check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you :

```
C = Ystg;
fid = fopen('file.dlm', 'wt');
for i=1:219
     fprintf(fid, '"%s"\t"%s"\t"%d"\t"%s"\t\n', C{i}{:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks bro that's work well but i need it as .txt is it possible to change .dlm to .txt ?

Comment: @F.caren  yes you could use txt file

Comment: @ daren shan last question I want to merge the first 3 cells  TCGA  A6 2677 to become  like this TCGA -A6-2677 , do you have an idea how to do it ?